# Sharepoint error details(call stack information) is not displayed in the sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to enable the error information in the Sharepoint site by modifying the web.config file.?. I have done the following changes in web.config  file

```
Callstack = true
CustomErrors mode = Off
Compilation debug = true
```

But still i am not able to get the call stack details(error details) in the sharepoint site for a error, instead of that i am getting this following error
"To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" file located in the root directory of the current web application". Please correct me on this?.

Answer (score 2):

custom errors mode off, (or on, I can never remember).  Then set debug=true.  The catch is that there are many different web.configs used by sharepoint.  There's one on the web application level (in inetpub, virtual directories), then there's one for layouts pages, control templates, etc in /web server extensions/14/.  You have to make these changes in all of the relevant web configs associated with your code.

And obviously, make sure this is always turned off in production for security reasons.

You do not need to do an iisreset, changing a web.config file will cause one automatically.

Comment: I had problem with application page and until i changed 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config as Robert suggested i wasn't able to see error details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run iisreset?

Make sure you're changes in the web.config look like these:

```
<customErrors mode=”Off” />

<SafeMode … CallStack=”true” … >

<trace enabled=”true” pageOutput=”true”/>
```

PS: Showing stack traces in a production environment is not recomenned, instead use a tool like ULSViewer for diving through the log files.